# setting the browser from command line using watir webdriver

Tags: watir-webdriver

my learning for ruby and watir webdriver is ongoing and i was wondering if there is a way to set the browser to be used from the command line when running a rb script, eg c:\ruby login.rb --set browser

I've done some looking around and can find nothing specific, any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I do.

My code has the following:

```
 case ENV['BROWSER']
  when 'ff', 'Firefox'
    @b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
    browser_name = 'Firefox'
  when 'chrome'
    @b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
    browser_name = 'Chrome'
  when 'debug'
    debug_profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
    debug_profile.add_extension "firebug-1.9.1-fx.xpi"
    @b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => debug_profile
    browser_name = 'Firefox (Firebug)'
  when 'mobile'
    mobile_profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
    mobile_profile['general.useragent.override'] = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en)
      AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0
      Mobile/1A535b Safari/419.3"
    @b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => mobile_profile
    browser_name = 'Mobile'
  when 'ie'
    @b = Watir::Browser.new :ie
    browser_name = 'Chrome'
  when 'headless'
    @b ||= Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs
    browser_name = 'phantomjs'
  else
   @b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
   browser_name = 'Firefox'
#@b ||= Watir::Browser.new :chrome

end
```

I can then set the browser variable in the cmd prompt before I run the test:

```
set BROWSER=Environment_ID
```

Comment: thanks Skjoldan, might take me a while to understand this, still early days in my learning, but thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I do the same with an environment variable; taking from @Skjoldan code, this would be the minimal to set your browser via environment variable:

```
case ENV['BROWSER']
when 'ff'
  @b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
else
  @b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
end
```

No environment variable set, defaults to chrome.